# ProgressBar and Snackbar don't show

Tags: android

I have an app that I'm slowly modernizing. All loading progress indication was being done with a ProgressDialog. In a couple of places I already changed it for a horizontal ProgressBar view with horizontal style (Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal). When I start loading I setVisibility(VISIBLE) and when loading stops I setVisibility(GONE). That was working fine.

Now I want to add SnackBars in some places. I had the Activity inherit from AppCompatActivity, changed parent theme to Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar (from android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar), and now the ProgressBar is gone. Also, the Snackbar doesn't even appear.

The Snackbar code is this:

```
Snackbar.make(view, "There was an error loading the content", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

No errors, it just doesn't show.

I guess there has to be some issue with styles somewhere, but I really don't know where to look.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT: A little more investigation reveals that the ProgressBar DOES show up, just off-screen. I had the ProgressBar at the bottom of a RelativeLayout. I moved it to the top, and now it appears and disappears as expected. So I'm guessing that at the bottom it appears, too, only off-screen. And the Snackbar is likely doing the same thing!

I don't have a solution yet, but at least I know a little more about what's going on…

Final EDIT: Disregard this question. Turns out there was a library being used that caused the issue.
So, if you come by this question with this same issue, and you're using jeremyfeinstein's slidingmenu library, check this link: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/issues/680#issuecomment-66604727